# "Квітування" чи "цвітіння"?

Tags: синоніми, правопис

**Чи можна вважати обидва терміни повними синонімами?**

> *Гортензія волотиста, завдяки не складній посадці та легкому догляду,
>   стане справжньою перлиною Вашого саду та радуватиме Вас розкішним
>   **квітуванням** довгі роки. Варто зазаначити, що Гортензія волотиста **цвіте** з червня по вересень.*

Зокрема в **СУМ** присутні два слова:

> ***[ЦВІТІННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cvitinnja)*** дія за значенням цвісти. Л*юбив Головатий степ і в ранню
>   пору весняного пробудження, і в час цвітіння, і в дні його прив'ядання*
>   (Спиридон Добровольський, Очаківський розмир, 1965, 22)
>
> ***[КВІТУВАННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kvituvannja)***  дія та стан за знач. квітувати. *Зима позаду, зелень
>   буйно пнеться вгору.., повітря сповнене запахів.. квітування* (Михайло
>   Чабанівський, Балканська весна, 1960, 231)

**Чи правильно використані слова в наведеному вище прикладі?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Квітування* й *цвітіння* не можуть уважатися повними синонімами. У слова *квітування* є переносне значення:

> 2. перен. **Процвітати, успішно розвиватися**.
>      *Нині, як, мабуть, ніколи, розвивається й квітує у нашій республіці художня самодіяльність* (Літературна газета, 21.X 1960, 2).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 136.

А оскільки наявний образний компонент, то синонімія лише за одним зі значень, отже неповна.